# open Logic analyzer for simulink model from matlab commandline

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, automated-tests, simulink, fpga

Example: I need to select particular signals from simulink model, log them, and open them in logic analyzer. 
All the three should be executed from matlab commandline. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Simulink has an extensive [API](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/classeslist.html?s_cid=doc_ftr). For marking signals for logging, I think you need to mark them for streaming, as is explained [on this page](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.sdi.marksignalforstreaming.html), since the Logic Analyzer uses the same signal selection mechanism as the SDI. The Logic Analyzer has an [API](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.logicanalyzer-system-object.html?s_tid=doc_ta#d119e251329) as well.